# Remove whitespace between baseline and symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, symbols, baseline, white-space

Despite my naive `anchor=center` specification, these four symbols are not aligned by their center:

[image: not aligned]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
    \node[anchor=center] at (0,  0) {*};
    \node[anchor=center] at (10, 0) {+};
    \node[anchor=center] at (20, 0) {-};
    \node[anchor=center] at (30, 0) {$\cdot$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My guess is that they carry invisible, solid whitespace due to their distance to their invisible baseline, which can be seen if we add `draw` to each node:

[image: extra space]

How do I remove this extra space so that the `center` of my symbols is actually the center of the black stuff I see?

(getting rid of the extra space at the right of `-` would be nice too)

Comment: Not a real solution, but you could print all glyphs in mathmode, which places them on the same height.

Comment: Maybe it is not what you are looking for, but when you write the symbols in mathmode, like `$+$` they are better aligned

Comment: @Max I know :) But `$+-*$` are not the same as `+-*`.. and this holds for many other symbols :\

Comment: @iago-lito That's true, it was merely a suggestion :)

Comment: @sporc They are indeed, but this is not my point since `$+$` differs from `+`, etc. Such a solution would hold for any symbol :)

Comment: your symbols, as you use them, has different distances from baseline.  on away, how you like to nullify those distances, is not possible.

Comment: @Zarko.. hmm, I was afraid of this. Is it because this whitespace somehow relates to the font itself? Is there no way to enter the font symbols from LaTeX interface?

Comment: To centre the dot you could `.` instead of `$\cdot$`. A more appropriate version of the asterisk is `\textasteriskcentered` (no packages required), but it still won't be perfectly centred. The `+` and `-` are already centred correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Circumscribe Thank you. This would be the beginning of a symbol-by-symbol workaround ;)

Comment: To answer an earlier question, the white space **is** associated with the font itself.  You could, on a case-by-case basis, apply a custom `\raisebox` to provide some uniformity. though the math mode approach seems best, to my way of thinking.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for this clarification :) Is there not a way then to access the font properties from LaTeX? A way of magically ending with `\shearWhitespaceFromSymbol{*}`?

Comment: Not with LaTeX itself, no, as LaTeX knows nothing of what a given glyph looks like...to LaTeX, they are merely boxes to be arranged.  There are font editing tools with which you might be able to construct a custom font

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes.. which makes the problem completely different then :) Thank you for this explanation! Is there any way to mark the question as "not answerable"?

Comment: You are putting these inside tikz nodes by themselves.  Does it matter whether you use a text font or a math font?  In fact, you might even use library tikz shapes like cloud (see pages 694-716).

Comment: @JohnKormylo It does, because the matter is not about the symbol themselves, but about removing this whitespace around, which is impossible according to StevenB.Segletes comment. Anyway, your suggestion and `\raisebox` are good workarounds :)

Comment: See \pgfuseplotmark{asterisk} (page 681).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The white space surrounding the glyph is called [sidebearing](https://ilovetypography.com/typography-terms/typography-terms-s/), and it is extracted from the bounding box of that glyph (for TeX this is slightly different). Sometimes the bounding box is larger than the glyph but sometimes it is smaller. These are determined by the font designer (and a lot more need to be taken care of, e.g., kerning pairs, positions of accents, etc.).

If you are using pdfLaTeX, the bounding box information can be found in the [`.tfm` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_font_metric). TeX doesn’t know anything about the actual glyph, and it only sees bounding boxes. So, as others have already pointed out in the comments, it is impossible to “remove” the white space, because TeX simply doesn’t know where the glyph actually sits within the bounding box.

However, a well-designed *math font* always center-aligns the binary/relation symbols and big operators. So, as others have suggested, you can use math `+`, `-`, and so on, *without specifying `anchor=center`*.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
    \node[draw,very thin] at (-10, 0) {\textit{f}};
    \node at (-15,  0) {\rlap{\color{red}\rule{70pt}{.1pt}}};
    \node at (0,  0) {$*$};
    \node at (10, 0) {$+$};
    \node at (20, 0) {$-$};
    \node at (30, 0) {$\cdot$};
    \node at (40, 0) {$\sum$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: bounding boxes]

Notice how `\textit{f}` extends beyond its bounding box.

Comment: That is a nice sumup, cheers :)